# Small yellow lines appearing

Tags: display, graphics-card, windows-8.1

I'm having strange yellow lines appearing on the right of various objects on my screen :

[image]

These lines seem to appear regardless on the application and always follow the form of the object next to it (see on the example, next to the first `G`).

The computer is a laptop(MSI-GT-70). The lines only seem to appear on the embedded monitor.

Comment: I changed the screeshot with a photo, but it's quite discrete. Any ideas for better testing ?

Comment: Test on some other monitor.

Comment: Please provide further details on your system (it’s a notebook?) and on how the display is connected.

Comment: @ali786 just did, the problem indeed seems to come from the monitor.

Comment: @DanielB it's a laptop, the problem appear on the embedded screen.

Comment: there are software to test your laptop screen on the internet. I think there are also YouTube videos to test your [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2eQhhMvi-U) screen. Compare the video with two screens - this will make it clear if it is a hardware issue or not

Comment: Well, my first guess would’ve been VGA, because it produces similar ghost images with low-quality connections. If this is an internal display, however, there’s something seriously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is working fine on other external monitors it seems that your monitor has gone bad and need to be replaced.

Comment: While this option certainly seems to work, would you know the reason behind the failure ? I'd like to avoid buying a new one, if I can.

Comment: how old is your laptop...?One of my classmate has got the same problem. and he neglected till his monitors line shaking very vastly and need to be replace it.

Comment: The laptop is one year old, the trouble appeared quite recently.

Comment: some times it will go out automatically. Use as it is. Is it in warranty.

Comment: It is still under warranty, I guess I'll use it. That's too bad, I would almost have like to try to repair it myself :] Thanks for your time, anyway !